# cpp: delay #include's until second pass

Tags: include, preprocessor

I'm running my source file through the C preprocessor twice before compiling it, and I want to delay The #include directives until the second pass.

Intuitively, I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
##include <zlib.h>
```

I just need a construct, that when preprocessed, will give `#include mylib`.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a reason for wanting to do this.  Care to enlighten?

Comment: @cHao: I'm using flex, and I'd like to preprocess the file to enable me to compose the regular expressions, but the file need to run through the preprocessor once again after being processed by flex.

Comment: Could you make your includes in a format the preprocessor won't recognize, and have flex change them to the "correct" format when it does its thing (assuming flex changes the files)?  Cause short of modifying the files, or doing conditional includes, you might not have much luck -- the preprocessor is going to have the same stuff to work with both times, so it'll do the same thing both times it runs.

Comment: @cHao: You're not understanding, I'm tryint to preprocess the flex source itself, not the input to the flex-based parser. I just need a construct, that when preprocessed, will give "#include mylib".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a macro, like

```
#define INCLUDE #include
```

and then when you include stuff, use the macro instead.

```
INCLUDE <zlib.h>
```

In GCC's preprocessor, at least, that gives me `#include <zlib.h>`.