# Is there a way to escape a C preprocessor directive?

Tags: c++, c, escaping, c-preprocessor

What I am trying to do is have the C preprocessor output `#ifdef`, `#else`, and `#endif` directives. That is, I would like to somehow "escape" a directive so that the output of the preprocessor includes the directive were the preprocessor to run on the output.

Is it possible to "escape" a CPP directive so that it is outputted by the preprocessor such that the output of an escaped directive would be a preprocessor directive if the CPP output were to be itself preprocessed?

Comment: @sidyll It would if the OP ran it through the preprocessor twice.

Comment: @sidyll: True. I am thinking about using the preprocessor to generate a project template.

Comment: @sidyll: "...if the CPP output were to be itself preprocessed"

Comment: What is the idea behind this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I suspect there are better tools for what you have in mind, like using a general purpose macro-processor or writing a preprocessing script in a convenient language.

Comment: What shall happen to `#ifdef`s in the not-included branch of a conditional inclusion? Your preprocessor would have to scan those as well which can lead to trouble.

Comment: Related (almost a dupe): [cpp: delay #include's until second pass](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6379404/319403)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A slight variant of [Marcelo Cantos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687634/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-c-preprocessor-directive/7687682#7687682) works for me on GNU cpp 4.4.3:

```
#define HASH(x) x

...

HASH(#)ifdef __cplusplus
class foo { };
HASH(#)endif
```

Comment: Creative use of preprocessor mechanics.

Comment: +1. The only (tiny) glitch is that it indents the `#` by one space. I believe some older preprocessors don't like that, so the convention is to indent the command (ifdef/endif/include...), but not the `#`. In any case, the answer is correct, and very creative.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Yeah, I have no idea where that space is coming from.  (It's not the obvious: the space appears even with `#define HASH(x)x`.)

Comment: I'd guess the space is something to do with the way that macro substitution avoids certain things that could be construed as token-pasting. So it doesn't want to emit a `#` without a preceding space, because the `#` could end up attached to a preceding token. Not sure, though.

Comment: @Marcelo: do we still have to worry about those pre-C89-standard compilers? I've never followed that convention, and it's never hit me, but then I first wrote C in 2002 or thereabouts, and I've never worked on truly decrepit systems unless you count Symbian/C++. The idea of writing to first edition K&R is sort of scary, I've never even had a copy...

Comment: @SteveJessop: I agree. I just though I'd mention it because I wasn't sure which compilers would be affected.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:** The following answer only appears to work on earlier versions of `cpp`. It breaks somewhere between 4.2.1 and 4.3.2. `gcc -E` and `g++ -E` break even earlier. See comments for the details.

---

Here's one trick that seems to work:

```
#define HASH() #

...

HASH()ifdef __cplusplus
class foo { };
HASH()endif
```

You'll have to use `cpp` directly, since a compiler will try to immediately consume the preprocessor output and won't know what to do with the unprocessed directives.

Comment: I get an error with GCC's preprocessor: "error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter"

Comment: @DanielTrebbien: How did you invoke it? I just pasted the above code into a text file and ran `cpp file.c`. It spat out a class definition surrounded by `#ifdef ... #endif`.

Comment: ... Ah, I see. You used the `g++ -E` suggestion. That appears to fail, for reasons I can't fathom at present. Perhaps `cpp` is more tolerant.

Comment: It fails for me using `cpp` too.  `cpp --version` prints `cpp (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2`, in case anyone is curious.  Edit: same result on another box with `cpp (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3`.

Comment: Mine is 4.2.1 (`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1` to be precise), but then again so is my g++.

Comment: I just tested on 4.5.2 (Linux) and it fails too. I guess my answer isn't so clever after all (or at least, it's cleverness has expired).

Answer (score 5):

Another trick that seems to work is:

```
#define EMPTY
EMPTY#ifdef
```

With GCC's preprocessor (version 4.5.2) I get:

```
 #ifdef
```

For some reason, this technique has the same leading space issue as [Ilmari Karonen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687634/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-c-preprocessor-directive/7687945#7687945), but this is probably not an issue with modern standards-conforming C preprocessors.