# Can gperf accept keywords defined by macros?

Tags: c++, c, gperf

I would like something like the following gperf input file:

```
%{
#include <keywords.h>
// the contents of which contain
// #define KEYWORD1_MACRO "keyword1"
// #define KEYWORD2_MACRO "keyword2"
%}
%%
KEYWORD1_MACRO
KEYWORD2_MACRO
%%
```

Unfortunately, gperf will interpret those as the stings "KEYWORD1_MACRO", etc.

The reason for this is that I have a protocol spec provided by another party as a header file, containing such `#define`s. So I don't have control over how they are defined, and I'd rather not have to write another preprocessing tool to `#include` the header and output the expansion of the macros as quoted strings, *only then* for use as a gperf input file.

Comment: How about asking `gcc -E` to deal with those `#include`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the following experiment which uses `gcc -E` to deal with those `#include`s.

keywords.h:

```
#define KEYWORD1_MACRO "keyword1"
#define KEYWORD2_MACRO "keyword2"
```

test.c:

```
%{
#include "keywords.h"
%}
%%
KEYWORD1_MACRO
KEYWORD2_MACRO
%%
```

Command: `gcc -E -o test.out.txt test.c`.
Then, the content in test.out.txt:

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "test.c"
%{
# 1 "keywords.h" 1
# 3 "test.c" 2
%}
%%
"keyword1"
"keyword2"
%%
```

The `#include`s are handled automatically. You can then do some text processing and feed into `gperf`.

Comment: Of course, why ask for gperf to part preprocess when gperf and cpp syntaxes are orthogonal enough.

Comment: I'll be using `cc -xc -E -P keywords.perf.in -o keywords.perf` and /EP with msvc.

Comment: [You may also need to 'escape' the pre-processor directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687634/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-c-preprocessor-directive) so that they make it through the initial pre-process, through gperf to the generated code to be included.   Also gperf's comment convention of a leading '#'  does not work well with the pre-processor and you need to escape this as well.  It is best to use quoted terminals/keywords with this mode.